Have you ever heard of the notion, that there is a messiah for every generation?
When I was steeped in Judaism, particularly Chabad, I remember this notion that there was "Moshiach in every Generation", implying that he is always alive, and waiting for the right moment if the generation warrants it.
One particular mention I remember was King Hezekiah, that he was supposed to Moshiach, which as it turns out is discussed in Sanhedrin 94a.
Anyways I am just wondering if this concept is a thing, if it has a name, or if I am just misremembering things.
Thanks.

https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9:%D7%90%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%9F/Moshiach_in_every_generation

I have indeed heard of this concept from many sources, it is not at all exclusive to Chabad.

There is a potential Moshiach in every generation. That person may not even know that's their role.

Here is a quote from Shut Chatam Sofer collected responsa Responsa 98:
והנה בהא דביאת בן דוד צריך אני להוציע הוצעה א' והוא כמו שהי' משרע"ה שהי' הגואל הראשון נזדקין שמנים שנה ולא ידע ולא הרגיש בעצמו שהוא יהי' גואל ישראל ואפי' כשאמר לו הקב"ה לך כי אשלחך אל פרעה מ"מ סירב ולא רצה לקבל על עצמו כן יהי' אי"ה הגואל האחרון ומיום שחרב בהמ"ק מיד נולד א' הראוי' בצדקתו להיות גואל ולכשיגיע הזמן יגלה אליו השי"ת וישלחו ואז יערה עליו רוחו של משיח הטמון וגנוז למעלה עד בוא וכאשר מצינו בשאול אחר שנמשח באה עליו רוח ממשלה ורוח הקודש אשר מלפנים לא הרגיש בעצמו כן הי' בגואל הראשון וכן יהי' בגואל האחרון והצדיק הזה בעצמו אינו יודע ובעונותינו כי רבו כבר כמה וכמה מתו ולא זכינו שיערה עליהם רוחו של משיח גם כי הם ראוי' לכך אבל הדור לא הי' ראוי' אולם כשיגיע אי"ה יגלה אליו ה' כמו למשה בסנה וישלחהו או לישראל לבד או למלך א' כמו לפרעה לומר שלח עמי:
He states that in each generation there is someone fitting to be Mashiach, but it is not revealed to the person himself until the generation is fitting to be redeemed.

An English translation of the entire quote would be a worthwhile addition to this answer.
